# "Failed to synchronize any databases - unexpected error"

Tags: upgrade, antergos

Trying to update in Antergos (with the GUI) gives me

[image: Error]

Here is my pacman.conf

```
#
# /etc/pacman.conf
#
# See the pacman.conf(5) manpage for option and repository directives

#
# GENERAL OPTIONS
#
[options]
# The following paths are commented out with their default values listed.
# If you wish to use different paths, uncomment and update the paths.
#RootDir     = /
#DBPath      = /var/lib/pacman/
#CacheDir    = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
#LogFile     = /var/log/pacman.log
#GPGDir      = /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
#HookDir     = /etc/pacman.d/hooks/
HoldPkg     = pacman glibc
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -C - -f %u > %o
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
#CleanMethod = KeepInstalled
#UseDelta    = 0.7
Architecture = auto

# Pacman won't upgrade packages listed in IgnorePkg and members of IgnoreGroup
#IgnorePkg   =
#IgnoreGroup =

#NoUpgrade   =
#NoExtract   =

# Misc options
#UseSyslog
#Color
#TotalDownload
CheckSpace
#VerbosePkgLists

# By default, pacman accepts packages signed by keys that its local keyring
# trusts (see pacman-key and its man page), as well as unsigned packages.
SigLevel    = Required DatabaseOptional
LocalFileSigLevel = Optional
#RemoteFileSigLevel = Required

# NOTE: You must run `pacman-key --init` before first using pacman; the local
# keyring can then be populated with the keys of all official Arch Linux
# packagers with `pacman-key --populate archlinux`.

#
# REPOSITORIES
#   - can be defined here or included from another file
#   - pacman will search repositories in the order defined here
#   - local/custom mirrors can be added here or in separate files
#   - repositories listed first will take precedence when packages
#     have identical names, regardless of version number
#   - URLs will have $repo replaced by the name of the current repo
#   - URLs will have $arch replaced by the name of the architecture
#
# Repository entries are of the format:
#       [repo-name]
#       Server = ServerName
#       Include = IncludePath
#
# The header [repo-name] is crucial - it must be present and
# uncommented to enable the repo.
#

# The testing repositories are disabled by default. To enable, uncomment the
# repo name header and Include lines. You can add preferred servers immediately
# after the header, and they will be used before the default mirrors.

#[testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[core]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

#[community-testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[community]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# If you want to run 32 bit applications on your x86_64 system,
# enable the multilib repositories as required here.

#[multilib-testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[multilib]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# An example of a custom package repository.  See the pacman manpage for
# tips on creating your own repositories.
#[custom]
#SigLevel = Optional TrustAll
#Server = file:///home/custompkgs

[antergos]
SigLevel = PackageRequired
Include = /etc/pacman.d/antergos-mirrorlist
```

...and my /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist...

```
# Arch Linux mirrorlist generated by Cnchi #
Server = http://mirrors.acm.wpi.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.rit.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.surlyjake.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://lug.mtu.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.kaminski.io/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.lty.me/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://il.mirrors.linaxe.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://arch.mirrors.ionfish.org/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://muug.ca/mirror/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://arch.tamcore.eu/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.23media.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.cinosure.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.one.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://arch.yourlabs.org/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.lucysan.net/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.honkgong.info/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.tyborek.pl/arch/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.compojoom.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.cyborg-connect.de/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.hactar.bz/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.mirrors.uk2.net/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.uni-plovdiv.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.my-universe.com/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.js-webcoding.de/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.united-gameserver.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.beccacervello.it/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.neuf.no/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.tuxdroid.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.archlinux.no/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.mirror.pkern.at/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.polymorf.fr/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://fooo.biz/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://k42.ch/mirror/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror5.bastelfreak.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.lastmikoi.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.n-ix.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.myrveln.se/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.f4st.host/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.gnomus.de/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.rnl.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://burek.archlinux.ba/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/arch/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror1.htu.tugraz.at/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.mirror.kangaroot.net/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://arch.mirror.far.fi/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.nl.leaseweb.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.pseudoform.org/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/ArchLinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.ip-connect.vn.ua/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://arch.midov.pl/arch/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://arch.nimukaito.net/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.puzzle.ch/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.selfnet.de/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.t-home.mk/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.byfly.by/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://pet.inf.ufsc.br/mirrors/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.swin.edu.au/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.zju.edu.cn/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/Linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.devilzc0de.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.is.co.za/mirror/archlinux.org/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.atviras.lt/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.tku.edu.tw/Linux/ArchLinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://foss.aueb.gr/mirrors/linux/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.c3sl.ufpr.br/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://ftp.wa.co.za/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://suro.ubaya.ac.id/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.manchester.m247.com/arch-linux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://archlinux.pop-es.rnp.br/$repo/os/$arch
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Arch does not have a GUI updater. What are you using?

Comment: Sorry @HalosGhost I'm using Antergos and the updater is based on Pamac.. But using pacman -Syu does the same thing

Comment: Antergos is not Arch.

Comment: @HalosGhost lol.. It's based on Arch